# jQuery - How do I test what type of selector is passing the value?

Tags: jquery

I am using the latest and greatest jQuery.  I am trying to make my code efficient and reusable throughout a specific site and want consolidate a block.

I have a piece of code that listens for a save button being clicked. When the save button is clicked, it figures out which selector was click and gets its id and value.

This code works perfectly for text boxes. I just want to be able to run select boxes, radio buttons, and check boxes through it too.  I need to handle the data differently depending on whether it's a checkbox, radio, or text field.

If I know the id of a selector, how can I easily test which type of selector it is?

In pseudocode:

```
if (SelectorType == 'radio') {
    // do radio stuff
} else if  (SelectorType == 'text') {
    // do test field stuff
} else if  (SelectorType == 'checkbox') {
    // do checkbox stuff
}
```

ANSWER

This is what I was trying to get at:

```
    var ThisField = $(this).parent().parent().children("td:eq(1)").children(":input").attr("id");

    var FieldType = $("#"+ThisField).prop("type");
    if (FieldType == "select-one") {
        alert("You are trying to save select box info!");
    } else  if (FieldType == "text") {
        alert("You are trying to save text info!");
    } else  if (FieldType == "checkbox") {
        alert("You are trying to save checkbox info!");
    } else  if (FieldType == "radio") {
        alert("You are trying to save radio info!");
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is `SelectorType`? Is it the actual selector? Or the element which triggered the event?

Comment: "If I know the id of a selector, how can I easily test which type of selector it is?"  Do you mean element instead of selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's prop method can give you the input type:

```
$("#foo").prop("type")
```

or even simpler:

```
document.getElementById("foo").type
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I asked for and exactly what you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use event.target:

```
$('input, select').click(function(e){
   alert(e.target.type);
   switch(e.target.type){
       case "checkbox": 
           break;
        case "radio":
            break;
          //and so on
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/v6fFn/

Comment: I could make this work, but it's not exactly what I was going for. The case/switch is a good idea though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use this.type? http://jsbin.com/iwilog/edit

Comment: I wish I could +2 this answer - big props to simple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach.

Wrap up common logic into a function. Pass the appropriate information to the function and handle the logic appropriately.

Comment: That's what I am doing. I am making a save "routine". When ANY save button is clicked, the function figures out which piece of data should be save and what type of element is storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by type,

```
$('#myinput:radio');
$('#myinput:text');
$('#myinput:checkbox');
```